# Low Video Frame Rate In Chrome and Other Browsers

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, safari

I am experiencing major frame drops for a video within chrome and other browsers like Firefox. For some reason, Safari seems to not be effected at all.

The video is an MP4 (H.254) at 24fps. The dimensions of the video are 1920x1080

I tried optimizing my JS code (I am new so there is probably much more to be done!). I also tried to increase the frame rate of the video (24 should appear somewhat smooth though) and still got the same lag.

```
function scrollVideo() {
        var video = document.getElementById('video');
          videoLength = video.duration,
          scrollPosition = $(document).scrollTop();

        video.currentTime =
          (scrollPosition / ($(document).height() - $(window).height())) *
          videoLength;
      }

      $(window).scroll(function (e) {
        scrollVideo();
      });
```

Comment: To be clear: You're changing the video frame as the user scrolls the page?

Comment: Yes, when the user scrolls the video plays.

Comment: You probably want to throttle/debounce the event, then, so it doesn't fire too often in a single second.

Comment: @ceejayoz added the debounce with a delay of 15 milliseconds. Didn't seem to do much. If I bumped it up higher there was visible lag in Safari. Any other suggestions?